# Does Ubuntu come with a zip file extracter?

Tags: zip

I have not seen a zip extractor for Ubuntu on the version I installed.

I like to root phones a lot of the time I have to zip and unzip files does Ubuntu come with a zip exacter for free?

Comment: It's Ubuntu. Please if you're going to ask questions, at least spend the time to type its name correctly. Also, which version did you install? Answers will vary depending on that.

Comment: okay sure i will try no promises on spelling! Ubuntu 10 is what i installed. i tried 3 different ones till i found one that would run right on this laptop im still figuring things out on using this system i haven't used Ubuntu since i was a teenager but im wanting to learn more and more.

Comment: Ubuntu 10 ? Do you mean 10.04 / 10.10 ? If so, that's very old - you should consider using a newer version, such as 16.04. Old versions of Ubuntu don't get security fixes or updates anymore.

Comment: `zip` / `unzip` isn't installed by default on 16.04, either.

Answer (score 7):

The standard Ubuntu (Unity desktop) comes with an application called `file-roller` or **Archive Manager**.

You can open zip files simply by double-clicking on them in your Files explorer.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` / `unzip` isn't (often) installed by default on Ubuntu... and it's such a common utility, used by so many shell scripts, you're going to need it eventually. (I'm always surprised when it's not there on each new Ubuntu system that I set up.)

There's a lot of little, common utils that are always missing on any new installation -- so, one useful feature of ubuntu is that when you try to run it, at least ubuntu will suggest what you need to install:

```
$ unzip foo
The program 'unzip' is currently not installed. To run 'unzip' please ask your administrator to install the package 'unzip'

$ zip foo
The program 'zip' is currently not installed. To run 'zip' please ask your administrator to install the package 'zip'
```

Also, to search for packages if you know the name (you can use a regexp or not; e.g, just search for `unzip` as a substring, or ends with `unzip$` or exactly matches `^unzip$`:

```
$ apt-cache search 'unzip$|zip$'  
gzip - GNU compression utilities
unzip - De-archiver for .zip files
zip - Archiver for .zip files
...
lunzip - data compressor based on the LZMA algorithm (decompressor)
lzip - lossless data compressor based on the LZMA algorithm
...
p7zip - 7z file archiver with high compression ratio
plzip - parallel, lossless data compressor based on the LZMA algorithm
rzip - compression program for large files
... (etc)
```

In short, the tl;dr:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zip unzip
```

Comment: (yes, I know `'unzip$|zip$'` is redundant, but it's an example that full regexp is supported & people don't have to pipe thru `egrep`)

Comment: Isn't there any newer version of zip? The one installed in Unbuntu 20.04 is v3.0 from 2008 (!). It lacks features like encrypting filenames when creating an encrypted archive.

Comment: Zip doesn't securely encrypt (at all), either encrypt after compression using separate utility, or use something like 7zip https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289999/how-to-zip-directory-with-encryption-for-file-names

Answer (score 1):

There is a default .zip extractor for ubuntu. Its name is "archive manager."
To zip the files (the appropriate word is to compress) just right click on the file/folder and select **compress**. To unzip the zipped (compressed) file right click on it and select **Extract here.**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Ubuntu flavor you use, it does come with a program/GUI to extract compressed files.

However if you need support for zip and other popular containers, install p7zip so your uncompress program work:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Comment: thank you when i go to the app place to download it it ask me to open it with an aplication what do i use?

Comment: When you go to the app place? I just gave you the command so you'll be able to extract .zip

Comment: oh thank you it worked. im get in the hang of it learning. i learn quick if showed or told thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, if you also need support for rar you should install either "rar" or p7zip-rar packages.